# Убрать отступ между блоками в левой колонке Bootstap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть ли вариант сделать так, чтобы четвёртый блок следовал сразу после первого без "отступа" сверху, который получается из-за высоты первой строки.

Есть вариант поделить контейнер на 2 дива по 50% каждый и закидывать в каждый блоки, тогда они будут друг под другом. А вот вариант без этого в природе существует?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="background-color:#ff0;" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="background-color:#f00; height:20px;" class="col-1 col-sm-6">1</div>
    <div style="background-color:#0f0; height:30px;" class="col-1 col-sm-6">3</div>
    <div style="background-color:#00f; height:40px;" class="col-1 col-sm-6">4</div>
    <div style="background-color:#0ff; height:55px;" class="col-1 col-sm-6">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Привет! Вот вариант решения твоего вопроса через flexbox:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-grid.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:#ff0; height:100px;" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around;" class="col-1 col-sm-12">
                <div style="width:100%; display:flex; flex-direction: column">
                    <div style="background-color:#f00; height:20px;">1</div>
                    <div style="background-color:#00f; height:40px;">4</div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%; display:flex; flex-direction: column">
                    <div style="background-color:#0f0; height:30px;">3</div>
                    <div style="background-color:#0ff; height:55px;">2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Создаешь flex-контейнер с направлением по горизонтали, в нем еще два flex-контейнера с направлением по вертикали и вставляешь в эти контейнеры нужные тебе блоки.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте блоку с цифрой `3` (который по счёту второй), класс со свойством `float: right;` на экранах шириной от `768px`.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pull-sm-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="background-color:#ff0;" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="background-color:#f00; height:20px;" class="col-1 col-sm-6">1</div>
    <div style="background-color:#0f0; height:30px;" class="col-1 col-sm-6 pull-sm-right">3</div>
    <div style="background-color:#00f; height:40px;" class="col-1 col-sm-6">4</div>
    <div style="background-color:#0ff; height:55px;" class="col-1 col-sm-6">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```